# Angular @Input component special characters

Tags: angular

I want to create a dynamic component that changes its background color using @Input. But using **'#'** in input value gives me a template parse error. How do I escape it?

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'layout-panel',
  template: `
  <div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': bgColor ? bgColor: 'white'}">
  </div>`,
  styles: ['']
})
export class PanelComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  @Input() bgColor: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.bgColor);
}
```

HMTL

```
<layout-panel [bgColor]="#000"></layout-panel>
```

Comment: Maybe this seems obvious but why not omit the # and put it into the template instead?

Comment: That has nothing to do with special characters. Your syntax is just wrong. Use `bgColor="#000"` or, if you really want an Angular expression, `[bgColor]="'#000'"`. `#000`is not a valid JavaScript (Angular) expression. `'#000'` on the other hand is a valid string literal.

Comment: the user might enter the word value of color.

Comment: Then you'll have it in some variable, and you'll use `[bgColor]="theVariableHoldingWhatTheUserEntered"`.

Comment: @JBNizet Is there no way to add the single quotes later in the ts file?

Comment: I don't get your question. You want to pass a literal JavaScript string. Literal strings in JavaScript are surrounded by quotes. But again, you can also just use `bgColor="#000"`, without the brackets arount bgColor, and AngularJS will understand that #000 is not an expression to evaluate, and will pass the literal string to the input.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you. Removing the brackets treats the value as is helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the input `#000` in single quotes like this: `'#000'`.

If you want the `bgColor`-input to be defined by the user, use a variable in the component.

[Working stackblitz of your example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ytupot)

Comment: I forked your stackblitz and added an example with just bgColor="#000". https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxaxgq?file=src/app/app.component.html.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'layout-panel',
  template: `
  <div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': bgColor ? `#${bgColor}`: 'white'}">
  </div>`,
  styles: ['']
})
export class PanelComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  @Input() bgColor: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.bgColor);
}
```

HTML

`<layout-panel [bgColor]="'#000'"></layout-panel>`**strong text**

Answer (score -1):

Use another format for transfer the color. For instance: rgb(0, 78, 89) or rgba(90, 89, 23, 0.4).

OR

For your component I would leave the '#' in component template and in input could be only '764598'.

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'layout-panel',
  template: `
  <div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': bgColor ? `#${bgColor}`: 'white'}">
  </div>`,
  styles: ['']
})
export class PanelComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  @Input() bgColor: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.bgColor);
}
```

HMTL

```
<layout-panel [bgColor]="000"></layout-panel>
```

Comment: That will pass the expression Angular expression `000` as input, i.e. a number that has the value 0. Not a string containing '000'. You don't understand how binding works.